Graceful Shutdown for PySpark Structured Streaming Job Throws Py4JNetworkError
I am working on a PySpark Structured Streaming job that reads data from a Kafka topic and processes it in real-time. I want to implement a graceful shutdown using signal handling, but I'm encountering an error when I try to stop the streaming query.
code:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, length
import signal
import sys

checkpoint_dir = "/tmp/checkpoints"
kafka_bootstrap_servers = "localhost:9092"

spark = SparkSession.builder \
  .appName("KafkaConsumer1") \
  .getOrCreate()

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.streaming.stateStore.stateSchemaCheck", "true")
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")

consumer_group_id = "consumer-group-1"

shutdown_requested = False

def shutdown_handler(signum, frame):
  global shutdown_requested
  print("Graceful shutdown initiated...")
  shutdown_requested = True
  query.stop()

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, shutdown_handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, shutdown_handler)

df = spark.readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_bootstrap_servers) \
  .option("assign", '{"sample-topic":[0]}') \
  .option("startingOffsets", "latest") \
  .option("kafka.group.id", consumer_group_id) \
  .load()

df = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING) as message")
df = df.withColumn("char_count", length(col("message")))

query = df.writeStream \
  .outputMode("append") \
  .format("console") \
  .option("checkpointLocation", f"{checkpoint_dir}/c1_consumer") \
  .start()

try:
  query.awaitTermination()
except Exception as e:
  print(f"Exception encountered: {e}")



`
When I press Ctrl + C to initiate a graceful shutdown, I get the following error:
ERROR:
root: Exception while sending command.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/spark_job/Documents/spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/clientserver.py", line 511, in send_command
    answer = smart_decode(self.stream.readline()[:-1])
RuntimeError: reentrant call inside <_io.BufferedReader name=3>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/spark_job/Documents/spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1038, in send_command
    response = connection.send_command(command)
  File "/home/spark_job/Documents/spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/clientserver.py", line 539, in send_command
    raise Py4JNetworkError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Error while sending or receiving
ERROR:root:Exception while sending command.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/spark_job/Documents/spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/clientserver.py", line 511, in send_command
    answer = smart_decode(self.stream.readline()[:-1])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/home/spark_job/Documents/spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 381, in signal_handler
    self.cancelAllJobs()
  File "/home/spark_job/Documents/spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 2446, in cancelAllJobs
    self._jsc.sc().cancelAllJobs()
  File "/home/spark_job/Documents/spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "/home/spark_job/Documents/spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py", line 179, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/spark_job/Documents/spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 334, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o27.sc

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/spark_job/Documents/spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1038, in send_command
    response = connection.send_command(command)
  File "/home/spark_job/Documents/spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/clientserver.py", line 539, in send_command
    raise Py4JNetworkError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Error while sending or receiving



Can someone help me understand why this error occurs and how to fix it?


The error you're seeing is likely due to the fact that the PySpark
driver program does not support signal handling in the way you're
attempting to use it. In your script, you are trying to handle SIGINT
and SIGTERM signals and stop a running Spark streaming query. However,
PySpark's driver program already sets signal handlers for these
signals (as well as others) in order to clean up its own resources
when a signal is received.
When you set your own signal handler, it overrides the one set by
PySpark. Then, when a signal is received, your signal handler is
invoked. Your signal handler attempts to stop the Spark streaming
query, which requires sending a command to the JVM running the Spark
application. However, at the same time, the PySpark driver program is
also trying to clean up its resources in response to the signal. This
results in a reentrant call, which is not supported, hence the
RuntimeError.
To get around this issue, you can add a shutdown hook to the JVM
running your Spark application to stop the streaming query when the
JVM is shutting down. Here is an example of how you can do this:

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, length
from py4j.java_gateway import java_import

checkpoint_dir = "/tmp/checkpoints"
kafka_bootstrap_servers = "localhost:9092"

spark = SparkSession.builder \
  .appName("KafkaConsumer1") \
  .getOrCreate()

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.streaming.stateStore.stateSchemaCheck", "true")
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")

consumer_group_id = "consumer-group-1"

df = spark.readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_bootstrap_servers) \
  .option("assign", '{"sample-topic":[0]}') \
  .option("startingOffsets", "latest") \
  .option("kafka.group.id", consumer_group_id) \
  .load()

df = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING) as message")
df = df.withColumn("char_count", length(col("message")))

query = df.writeStream \
  .outputMode("append") \
  .format("console") \
  .option("checkpointLocation", f"{checkpoint_dir}/c1_consumer") \
  .start()

java_import(spark._jvm, 'org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery')

def stop_query():
  query.stop()

shutdownHookManager = spark._jvm.org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager
shutdownHookManager.addShutdownHook(stop_query)

query.awaitTermination()


This script uses PySpark's JavaGateway to import classes from the JVM
and add a shutdown hook that stops the streaming query. The shutdown
hook will be invoked when the JVM is shutting down, which will occur
when the PySpark driver program is exiting in response to a signal.


Hi @Jay Shankar Gupta thanks for response , sorry  i am very much beginner in these structured streaming when i ran the above code i am getting the error as
py4j/protocol.py", line 298, in get_command_part
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'
not able to understand what error is this and what need to be done here

Sudhir suggested adding brackets after stop_query, so that stop_query executes without returning and None is passed as the parameter to addShutdownHook.

To overcome this error object has no attribute '_get_object_id' ,
shutdownHookManager.addShutdownHook(stop_query()) worked for me

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review
